# How to write a BigQuery query that produces the count of the unique transactions and the combination of column names populated

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I’m trying to write a query in BigQuery that produces the count of the unique transactions and the combination of column names populated.

I have a table:

| TRAN CODE | Full Name | Given Name | Surname | DOB | Phone |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |

The result set I’m after is:

| TRAN CODE | UNIQUE TRANSACTIONS | NAME OF POPULATED COLUMNS |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 3 | Full Name |
| A | 4 | Full Name,Phone |
| B | 5 | Given Name,Surname |
| B | 10 | Given Name,Surname,DOB,Phone |

The result set shows that for TRAN CODE A

3 distinct customers provided Full Name
4 distinct customers provided Full Name and  Phone #

For TRAN CODE B
5 distinct customers provided Given Name and Surname
10 distinct customers provided Given Name, Surname, DOB, Phone #

Currently to produce my results I’m doing it manually.

I tried using ARRAY_AGG but couldn’t get it working.

Any advice work be appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Sample data would really help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider below approach - no any dependency on column names rather than TRAN_CODE - quite generic!

```
select TRAN_CODE, 
  count(distinct POPULATED_VALUES) as UNIQUE_TRANSACTIONS, 
  POPULATED_COLUMNS
from (
  select TRAN_CODE, 
    ( select as struct 
        string_agg(col, ', ' order by offset) POPULATED_COLUMNS, 
        string_agg(val order by offset) POPULATED_VALUES, 
        string_agg(cast(offset as string) order by offset) pos
      from unnest(regexp_extract_all(to_json_string(t), r'"([^"]+?)":')) col with offset
      join unnest(regexp_extract_all(to_json_string(t), r'"[^"]+?":("[^"]+?"|null)')) val with offset
      using(offset)
      where val != 'null'
      and col != 'TRAN_CODE'
    ).*
  from `project.dataset.table` t
)
group by TRAN_CODE, POPULATED_COLUMNS
order by TRAN_CODE, any_value(pos)
```

below is output example

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I *think* you want something like this:

```
select tran_code,
       array_to_string(array[case when full_name is not null then 'full_name' end,
                             case when given_name is not null then 'given_name' end,
                             case when surname is not null then 'surname' end,
                             case when dob is not null then 'dob' end,
                             case when phone is not null then 'phone' end
                            ], ','),
        count(*)                
from t
group by 1, 2
```

Answer (score 1):

@Gordon_Linoff's solution is the best, but an alternative would be to do the following:

```
SELECT
  TRAN_CODE,
  COUNT(TRAN_ROW) AS unique_transactions,
  populated_columns
FROM (

  SELECT
    TRAN_CODE,
    TRAN_ROW,
    # COUNT(value) AS unique_transactions,
    STRING_AGG(field, ",") AS populated_columns
  FROM (

    SELECT
      * EXCEPT(DOB),
      CAST(DOB AS STRING ) AS DOB,
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER () AS TRAN_ROW
    FROM
      sample) UNPIVOT(value FOR field IN (Full_name,
        Given_name,
        Surname,
        DOB,
        Phone))
  GROUP BY
    TRAN_CODE,
    TRAN_ROW )

GROUP BY
  TRAN_CODE,
  populated_columns
```

But this should be more expensive...